# jsonpath filter not working as expected in gatlign

Tags: jsonpath, gatling

In a gatling scenario I am using a jsonPath check to save a value. The json path expression is the following

```
$.myentries[?(@.progs.length > 0)].users[*].id
```

If I test it in an online evaluator on the following

```
{
  "myentries" : [ {
    "users" : [ {
      "id" : "T62"
      } ],
    "progs" : [ ]
  }, {
    "users" : [ {
      "id" : "T52"
      }
    ],
    "progs" : [ {
      "start" : "2023-07-12T09:46:00",
      "end" : "2023-07-12T10:01:00"
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

I get the answer that I expect ( ["T52"] ). But in gatling that doesn't work at all, I always get an empty array. Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

There’s no such thing as a ‘.length’ in the [original JsonPath paper](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).

This is something that was invented in the library underneath your online evaluator.

JsonPath doesn’t have a specification and results and features can greatly vary between implementation.
I recommend that you use JMESPath instead. It has a proper specification so results are almost certain to be identical across implementations and Gatling supports it as well.